# Shell scripting to print multiples of 5 including 1 and 100

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
x=1
while [ "$x" -lt 20 ]
do
    echo "$x"
    x=("$x" * 5);
done
```

Getting error as syntax error near unexpected token `done'
and getting output as 11111111111....

Comment: also see: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion. `x=(...)` is an array assignment

Comment: Can you please help me over here to get the multiples of 5 include 1 and 100

Comment: 1 isn't a multiple of 5. 0, 5, 10 etc are.

Answer (score 2):

Use the right syntax for the calculation:

```
x=$((x*5))
```

Comment: Hi pLumo, Thanks that worked for the syntax.Can you please let me know how to get the multiples of 5 including 1 and 100. so that i can move further.

Comment: Again: learn your 5 times table. 0 x 5 is 0; 1 * 5 is 5; there is no integer that you multiply by 5 to get 1. Just echo 1 at the top, because it is an irregular series anyway. Also, if you want 100, you need to permit the iteration where x is 20, so use -le instead of -lt. Or you might just try: echo 1 {5..100..5}; or: for x in 1 {5..100..5}; do echo $x; done; and see which you prefer.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
x=1

echo "$x"

while [ $x -lt 20 ]
do
x=$(( x*5 ));
echo "$x"
(( x++ ))
done       The output I'm getting is 1 5 30 155.